# Keyboard shortcut to move file to another splitter window

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

I often work with two editor windows side-by-side via the [Split Vertically](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-code-editor.html#split_screen) command.

I am able to move a file from one window to another by dragging the tab to the desired destination, but this requires taking my hands off of the keyboard.

I'd like to be able to move an open file from one side of the splitter to the other with a keyboard shortcut. Any ideas?

I'm using the latest versions of PyCharm CE (3.4.1) and WebStorm (10.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
2. Search for `opposite` in search field
3. Locate `Other | Move to Opposite Group` action
4. Assign any desired shortcut
5. Use it

**P.S.**
This action is also available via editor tab context menu (as long as you have 2 or more splitters).