# How to swap splitter windows in Intellij / PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, splitter

After splitting the current editor window I navigated to the right one and then created a Scratch File. However the new Scratch File was opened in the left splitter instead.

[image]

I can not find any way to swap the contents of the splitter windows.  Does such a capability exist? Otherwise how to achieve the same result: do I need to somehow close both windows and open them and in what order?

I am on: `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-212.5080.55, built on August 23, 2021`.

Comment: The problem is not reproduced for my work environment. What IDE version do you use? `Help | About` Does it help if you temporarily disable all [third party plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html)?

Comment: @EgorKlepikov updated the question with the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a similar build: PyCharm 2021.2.1 (Professional Edition) August 25, 2021.

What I think might be happening is that it's probably not a bug but you **momentarily loose focus** between the split screens when creating the scratch file. This can be hard to spot because the visual queue is subtle: carefully look at the color underlining the tab. (One of the reasons I'm posting is in case a user with visual impairments or who is color blind runs into this problem). See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of splitter tabs]

Try choosing the tab you want and create a scratch file with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

> I can not find any way to swap the contents of the splitter windows.

The easiest way to do this is configuring and using the [Move to Opposite Group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32746318) action. Another alternative is using the [Goto Next Splitter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8611033) action.

It's not entirely possible to fully automate the two above actions into a single keystroke to swap both tabs between the splitters, even if you [record a macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) choosing the last splitter requires a click.

Comment: you don't seem to be a 'bad' coder to me