# PyCharm: Split windows, then navigate in the **current** window?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

1. I used "Split right" in PyCham
2. I see file "left.py" on the left side and "right.py" on the right side.
3. The cursor is in "left.py".
4. I use shift-shift to navigate to a method in a third file called "new.py"
5. PyCharm opens the file new.py on the **right** side.
6. That's very strange.
7. I want PyCharm to navigate to the new location in the window where the cursor is. See Step 3.

Is there a way to configure PyCharm to navigate always the side which contains the cursor, and not the other window?

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04

```
PyCharm 2021.2.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-212.5457.59, built on October 19, 2021
Licensed to Thomas Güttler
Subscription is active until January 5, 2022.
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.40 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-88-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1924M
Cores: 4

Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Comment: I just tried this on Windows and after step 4 (shift-shift) the new file is opened on the correct side of the split (the side where you have the cursor in a file - I tried it on both sides). Might be a bug specific to your OS or perhaps there's some condition to reproduce this that my IDE doesn't have configured. (My bet is on a bug). The shift-shift functionality is called [Search Everywhere](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/when-the-shift-hits-the-fan-search-everywhere/) I searched the IDE but it's not possible to configure on which split it opens (defaults to the split with cursor).

Comment: A similar issue was reported earlier this month which I also couldn't reproduce, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69425257). (I assumed it could be caused by a loss of focus when clicking in the Project Tool Window.) At this point I'd recommend reporting this on the [JetBrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com).